# Node.js express: trying to get text from HTML form, req.body empty

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I'm trying to build a basic text to speech form, but I cannot grab the text from the form.
I'm trying to get text from an HTML form using an express server and req.body turns up empty every time. I've tried using body-parser and changing the enctype on the form, nothing seems to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>index.html</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>Speech!!</h1>
    <main>
        <form action="/speak" method="POST" id="speak-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div id="text-container">
                <label for="text-box">Text to Speech!</label>
                <input type="text" id="text-box" title="text" placeholder="Type what you want to say here!"/>
            </div>
            <div class="button-container">
                <button type="submit" id="submit-button">Speak!</button>
            </div>
            <div class="button-container">
                <button type="reset" id="clear-form">Clear Text</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
    const express = require("express");
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const app = express();
    const configRoutes = require("./routes");

    app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 

    configRoutes(app);

    app.listen(3000, () => {
      console.log("Speech Server");
    });
```

index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const speakRoutes = require("./speak");

const constructorMethod = (app) => {
    app.use("/speak",speakRoutes);

    app.use("*", (req,res) => {
        res.sendFile("index.html", { root: "./public" });
    });
};

module.exports = constructorMethod;
```

speak.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/", async (req,res) => {
    console.log("POST");
    console.log(req.body);
    res.sendFile("index.html", { root: "./public" });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I would greatly appreciate some help! Thank you!

Comment: Hello Kristen, can you confirm if the POST request is being received by your server and can you go to your browser inspect element tab and check the network option. That will show you if the API is being sent properly from the browser.

Secondly I recommend you use `javascript` to control the form and submission of data. Have you done that before?

Answer (score 1):

Your input has no name, give your input a name so you know what property to look for in the form:

```
<input type="text" id="text-box" name="whatever" ... />
```

---

EDIT: A client-only example. One field has a name.

```js
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log($(e.currentTarget).serialize());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <h1>Speech!!</h1>
    <main>
        <form action="/speak" method="POST" id="speak-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div id="text-container">
                <label for="text-box">Text to Speech!</label>
                <input type="text" id="text-box" title="text" placeholder="Type what you want to say here!" name="whatever" />
                <input type="text" id="text-box" title="text" placeholder="I have no name so I won't be sent!" />
            </div>
            <div class="button-container">
                <button type="submit" id="submit-button">Speak!</button>
            </div>
            <div class="button-container">
                <button type="reset" id="clear-form">Clear Text</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </main>
```

Comment: thank you for the quick response! i added a name field to the textbox on my end and it is still not appearing in req anywhere. i am relatively new to web dev, what language did you use to retrieve the form data, like with $ and all?

Comment: That is jQuery (https://jquery.com/) -- it was added to simplify making an example you can run in your browser  here on this page -- you wouldn't need to use that in your real code since you want the data to go to a real server (though you could use it to ensure your form data is captured in the same way the example does)

Comment: Are you using your browser's "developer tools" console to watch the network request? You can confirm if the form data is being sent or not. E.g. see: https://datawookie.netlify.app/blog/2016/09/view-post-data-using-chrome-developer-tools/

Comment: i was using the terminal inside my IDE to see the value of req.body (always just {}), i just checked using the developer tools and the correct value of the textbox is appearing in the Form Data section

Comment: What version of epxress are you using?

Comment: i'm using version 4.17.1

Comment: And, just to confirm -- you are seeing your output of `console.log("POST");` and there are no errors and you have inspected the contents of `req` and your form data is nowhere to be found?

Comment: yes, that's right! i took most of this code i have from an existing project with forms and an express server that worked just fine, which is why i'm especially confused

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my own issue! It worked by changing `post` to `get` in the route and the html form method, and `req.body` to `req.query`